# d3 js not working well

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Q5Jag/3047)

I am now studying d3.js and found very mysterious thing.
The dataSet is [10,20,30,40] (four)
But it is showing only three circles.

```
var svg = d3.select('svg');
var dataSet = [10, 20, 30, 40]

var circle = svg.selectAll('circle')
    .data(dataSet)
    .enter()
    .append('circle')
    .attr({
        r: function (d) {
            return d
        },
        cx: function (d, i) {
            return i * 100 + 50
        },
        cy: 50,
        fill: 'red'
    });
```

I saw the inspect and it contains 4 circles, very mysterious.

Someone help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add appropriate width for svg element. Currently, the fourth circle do not fit to svg.

```js
var svg = d3.select('svg');

var dataSet = [10, 20, 30,40];

var circle = svg
    .attr('width', 500) // <-- !!!
    .selectAll('circle')
    .data(dataSet)
    .enter()
    .append('circle')
    .attr({
        r:function(d){ return d },
        cx:function(d, i){ return i * 100 + 50 },
        cy:50,
        fill: 'red'
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant see the last circle, because it lies outside of the image.